# Laravel filter not redirecting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, http-redirect

I have this in routes.php

```
Route::when('/user/*', 'check_login');
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
```

and this in filter.php

```
Route::filter('check_login', function()
{
    if (Session::get('username'))
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

I want to check the session if the url pattern is `user/*`. and if session exist  call
controller functions according to URL.

Now the filter not working.

Comment: What happens if you change the routes.php to 

    Route::when('/user', 'check_login');
    Route::when('/user/*', 'check_login');
    Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');

Comment: `/user/*` will match `/user/xyz` but not `/user`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small tweek

`Route::when('user*', 'check_login');`

`check_login` filter gets called on every URL that begins with `user` in URL